# How to get the color of a pixel in an image in C++ (sfml)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sfml

I am working on a simple racing game where you drive a car on a track. 
The track is grey and the background green, and any time the color i get on a given point (the front of the car) is not grey, the car should stop because it went out of the track.

However the track is NOT drawn with sfml, rather a downloaded image i made. 
So, is there any method for getting the color of a pixel on an IMAGE, as long as the rgb values match?

Here is the pseudo code to do this:

while game is running
get color (car x value, car y value)
if color is not grey
car stops

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `sf::Color` of a pixel in an `sf::Image` by using the appropriate method: [`sf::Image::getPixel`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.0/classsf_1_1Image.php#acf278760458433b2c3626a6980388a95). It takes X and Y coordinates.

Example:

```
sf::Image track;

if (!track.loadFromFile("track.jpg"))
{
   // oops, loading failed, handle it
}

sf::Color color = track.getPixel(0, 0); // gets the color of the upper left corner pixel
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use sf::Image's getPixel(int x, int y) funciton. Your pseudo code would look something like this:

```
sf::Image track;
sf::Color grey_color; // You'll need to define what the grey color is.
                      // Take sf::Color(100, 100, 100) as an example.
if (!track.loadFromFile("track.jpg")) {
    std::cout << "Uhoh" << std::endl;
}

while (gameIsRunning) {
    sf::Color color_at_car = track.getPixel(car.getx(), car.gety());
    if (color_at_car != grey_color) {
        car.stop();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!